# Creating an Inheritance/Composition Structure in Java

Tags: java, oop

I am looking for advise on approaches to the following situation.  I think an inheritance structure will be helpful, to reduce the synchronization code.   Any recommendation on the ideal way to create this model or point me to a similar example.

The model is shown below.

There are several GrandParents.  A GrandParent can have several Parents and similarly a Parent can have several children.  There seems to be two "inheritance" structure, one for Parent/Child and the other for "IncomeStatements".

The "grandIncomeStatement" and the "parentIncomeStatement" are a cumulative Income Statement of its Children as well its own IncomeStatement.  They have to in synch whenever there are any changes to the "myIncomeStatement".

For now, I have created a "class IS(IncomeStatement)" which has common attributes without any inheritance and written code around changes - to the IncomeStatements at each level.

```
class GrandParent {
   ObjectIS myIncomeStatement;
   ObjectIS grandIncomeStatement;
}
class Parent {
   ObjectIS myIncomeStatement;
   ObjectIS parentIncomeStatement;
}
class Child {
   ObjectIS myIncomeStatement;
}
```

Comment: Instead of using ObjectIs , you can always use polymorphism then late with `instance of` operator you can check btw that will not be needed because dynamic binding will invoke right function

Comment: There is no such "Class" declaration in Java it should be lowercase "class ....".

Comment: @JorgeCampos.  Editing issue.  Made the changes.

Comment: Do you actually need separate classes for grandparent, parent, and child?  That's pretty unnatural -- after all, in natural language, a grandparent is also a parent and a child.

Comment: Thanks @JohnBollinger.  Actually I have done that in the model.  I am trying to find a better way to map - cumulative and the personal income statements, so that I can keep them in sych with recursive logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A different approach would be to have `Person` and it having list of children.

```
public class Person {
    List<Person> children;
    ObjectIS myIncomeStatement;
    ObjectIS familyIncomeStatement;

    public ObjectIS getFamilyIncomeStatement() {
        ObjectIS is = new ObjectIS();
        for(Person p: children) {
            is.income += p.familyIncomeStatement.income;
        }
        is.income += this.myIncomeStatement.income;
        return is;
    }
}

// sample objectIS class
public class ObjectIS {
    private int income;
}
```

Edit: So you can probably have a recursive way to calculate the familyIncome (you'll obviously have a stricter access control, proper getters/setters)

Comment: Thanks @ajc.  This will work.  Is there a way to model the family - or the cumulative income statements, where the associations are maintained (with changes in Child Income Statements as well as its own income statements.   To, write a recursive logic to synch the income statements.